# Initializing Array of Type Stucture

Tags: c

```
    enum denomination
    {
        FIVE_CENTS, TEN_CENTS, TWENTY_CENTS, FIFTY_CENTS, ONE_DOLLAR, 
        TWO_DOLLARS, FIVE_DOLLARS, TEN_DOLLARS
    };

    struct DENOM_NAME
    {
        char name[MAX_NAME];
        enum denomination denom;
    };

    /* Table of names and matching denominations */
    static struct DENOM_NAME denomTable[8] = {
        { "5",  FIVE_CENTS },
        { "10",  TEN_CENTS },
        { "20", TWENTY_CENTS },
        { "50", FIFTY_CENTS },
        { "100", ONE_DOLLAR },
        { "200", TWO_DOLLARS },
        { "500", FIVE_DOLLARS },
        { "1000", TEN_DOLLARS }
    };
```

I've learnt that initializing an array with values is allowed but somehow the compiler is complaining about mixed declarations and code (c90 btw). How do I fix this?

Comment: How is `enum denomination` defined? What exactly is the error message?

Comment: change enum in declaration of struct to int or char and define previously you enum.

The enum does not create cells in memory, so it is not suitable for structure

enum like #define, it gives the names of some constants

Comment: You have some executable code before a declaration.  Look at the lines just before the one the compiler complains about.  And, if possible, upgrade to a C11 (or even just C99) compiler, or upgrade the compilation options to C99 or (preferably) C11.

Comment: A minimal example compiles fine in C90 and C99, http://ideone.com/lRpOXe

Comment: Posting the exact error message will be really helpful

Comment: Even with the edit and extra code, the problem is not on display.  Show the code from the start of the block (function) down to the line where the error is reported.  You may have `printf("Hi\n");` or `variable = value;` or something before these lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the error from a C89/C90 compiler with code like this:

```
void function(void)
{
    int i = 23;         /* OK - initialization */
    printf("%d\n", i);  /* OK - executable statement (code) */
    enum denomination   /* BAD - declaration mixed with code */
    {
        FIVE_CENTS, TEN_CENTS, TWENTY_CENTS, FIFTY_CENTS, ONE_DOLLAR, 
        TWO_DOLLARS, FIVE_DOLLARS, TEN_DOLLARS
    };
    …
```

You could have a plain function call, an assignment, a stray extra semicolon, or something before the line where the errors start.

Note that C99 and C11 follow the lead of C++ and allow variable definitions at (almost) any point in a function (statement block).  The outline code above is fine in C99 and C11.

Comment: That would do it.  `int denomination = 0;` would be fine; `int denomination; denomination = 0;` followed by the type definitions is not OK.

Comment: Got it thanks. Apparently it's this line I had:
int denomination;
denomination = 0;
Fixed by int denomination = 0;